# Determine Original Exit Status Code

Tags: c, linux, error-code

In a software baseline I am maintaining, there are 150 statements spread out amongst various C applications that make a call to either another Linux command (e.g. `rm -rf ...`) or custom application using `status = system(cmd)/256`. When either is called, the status code returned from either the Linux command or custom application is divided by **256**. So that when the status code is greater than 0, we know there was a problem. However, the way the software was written, it doesn't always log what command or application returned the status code. So that if the status code was say 32768, when divided by 256, the status code reported is **128**.

The software is old and while I could make changes, it would be nice if any of the commands called or applications called reported their original status code elsewhere.

Is there a way to determine the original status code in a standard Linux log file and the application which returned it?

Comment: Write a wrapper (function or macro), which calls the original `system()` and logs the full result before returning.

Comment: A status code returned by `system` fits in one byte unless the command got a signal (e.g. crashed with `SIGSEGV`)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Then why divide by 256? I am seeing error codes such as 32768.

Comment: Read *carefully* [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) man page and look inside your system's `/usr/include/bits/waitstatus.h` and `/usr/include/stdlib.h` for the macro defining `WTERMSIG` etc. Actually, your program should use such macros `WIFEXITED`, `WEXITSTATUS`, `WIFSIGNALED`, `WTERMSIG`, etc.... on the result of [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function.

Answer (score 5):

**How to write a wrapper**

*Following an example on how to apply a wrapper around the libc function `system()`.*

Create a new module (translation units) called `system_wrapper.c` like so:

The header `system_wrapper.h`:

```
#ifndef _SYSTEM_WRAPPER
#define _SYSTEM_WRAPPER

#define system(cmd) system_wrapper(cmd)

int system_wrapper(const char *);

#endif
```

The module `system_wrapper.c`:

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* to prototype the original function, that is libc's system() */
#include "system_wrapper.h"

#undef system

int system_wrapper(const char * cmd)
{
  int result = system(cmd);

  /* Log result here. */

  return result;
}
```

Add this line to all modules using `system()`:

```
#include "system_wrapper.h"
```

Comment: Good idea.. it looks like system() calls /bin/sh -c. Is there a way to force it to call /bin/sh -x -c instead? http://linux.die.net/man/3/system

Comment: What I mean is that in the C programs, it makes a call to the `stdlib` **system** and according to the link I posted in the comment above, it calls /bin/sh -c. I assume this is hardcoded in `stdlib`. Not sure if this can be changed without forcing a recompile

Comment: I'd say recomopiling the libc should not be an option.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing `-x -c <cmd>` instead of `-c <cmd>`?

Comment: You could modify `/bin/sh` instead. Or apply another wrapper on this level linking `/bin/sh` to your own script which then calls the original shell program.

Answer (score 2):

As I commented, [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function returns the result of a waiting syscall like 
[waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html). (Please follow the links to the man pages).

So you should improve your program to use `WIFEXITED`, `WIFSIGNALED`, `WEXITSTATUS`, `WTERMSIG` standard (Posix) macros on the result of calls to `system` (except when that result is `-1`, then use `errno`).

Coding

```
 status = system(cmd)/256;
```

is unreadable (to the human developer) and unportable.

<sup>I guess the coder who coded that wanted to catch interrupted commands....</sup>

You should replace that with

```
 status = system(cmd);
 if (status < 0) /* e.g. fork failed */
   do_something_with_error_code (errno);
 else if (status == 0) /* cmd run without errors */
   do_something_to_tell_command_exited_ok ();
 else if (WIFEXITED(status)) /* cmd got an error */
   do_something_with_exit_code (WEXITSTATUS(status));
 else if (WIFSIGNALED(status))  /* cmd or the shell got a signal */
   do_something_with_terminating_signal (WTERMSIG(status));
```

BTW, using `system("rm -rf /some/dir");` is considered bad practice (what if the user made his own `rm` in his `$PATH`) and not very efficient. (You could for example use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) with [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)) or at least `/bin/rm -rf` ; but what about spaces in the directory name or dirty [`IFS` tricks](http://nixshell.wordpress.com/2007/09/26/ifs-internal-field-separator/)?)

Comment: Basile, could you please clarify the wording in your last sentence? To others: when using `nftw(..., FTW_DEPTH)`, `unlink()` for files, and `rmdir()` for empty directories (that's why you want to do a depth-first search -- to delete files first), all possible file names are handled correctly (as long as you don't set a locale, or set the `C` or `POSIX` locale, as non-UTF-8 sequences in UTF-8 locales will usually abort C library functions). The issues with spaces or dirty IFS tricks et cetera occur only with `system()`.