# How to cover a function by another function?

Tags: c, gcc, attributes

Test code:

```
void print1()
{
     printf("functon1 printing\n");
}  
//I can add other function like:
void print2()
{
    printf("function 2 printing\n");
}
// Is there a way when I call print1 in main, actually print2 works?
// I mean if print2 exist , main use print2 . else use print1.
// Hope no macro answer , any gcc attribute way is best! For I want use it in more complex code.
int main()
{
    print1();
    return 0;
}
```

Here I want the program  print another string like :"function 2 is printing ".

*NOTE:* **I can't change the main function and print1 function in some case!!**

I hope there is a way I use another function covered the `function1` and print my string.

I use GCC , I know little about _ *attribute* _ .However , I think gcc can do this.

Is it possible:

```
 any gcc attribute way is best! For I want use it in more complex code.
```

Or it just gcc attribute can't do that?

Can anyone give me a example?

Thanks .

Comment: defined your function as: `void print1(char* text){ printf(text);}` and call from `main()` as: `printf1("functon1 printing\n");`  or `printf1("functon 2 is printing\n");`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan I can't change the `main` and `print1` function!

Comment: @LidongGuo Can you change the rest of the file?

Comment: @sfstewman Yes I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't modify anything in between `print1()` and `main()`, you can change what `print1()` does with a macro:

```
void nada (const char *s) {}
#define printf puts("function2 printing"); nada
```

If you are allowed add code between `print1()` and `main()`, you can define a new function, and then use a macro to define `print1` to be the new function instead.

---

The problem with the problem as you have presented it is that your imposed requirements on the solution limited the number of ways to solve the problem.

- Both the function you want to override and the function you want to override it with are in the same source file.
- You stipulated that `print1()` could not be modified.
- You stipulated that how `print1()` is called in `main()` could not be modified.

All these restrictions make it difficult to provide a nice flexible solution to your problem, which is why you got these macro style solutions. Allow me to describe a few solutions that are free from these restrictions.

**Idea #1:** Use the `weak` attribute on the function you want to override with. Then, redefine `print1()` to check for the presence of the override:

```
extern void print2 () __attribute__((weak));

void print1 ()
{
    if (print2) { print2(); return; }
    puts("function1 printing");
}
```

Since `print2()` is declared with the `weak` attribute, you can test to see if a definition for it is present. If it is, `print1()` invokes that instead of doing what it would normally do.

This allows you to leave all the function definitions in the same source file, but you need to modify `print1()`.

**Idea 2:** Separate `print1()` from `main()` into a separate file. Use the linker's `-wrap print1` option to make the program resolve `print1` in the object to the symbol `__wrap_print1` instead. When this option is used, references to the symbol `__real_print1` resolve to the original `print1`, but that feature is not needed for this solution.

```
$ cat main.c
extern void print1 ();    

int main ()
{
    print1();
}
$ cat print.c
#include <stdio.h>

void print1 () { puts("function1 printing"); }
void print2 () { puts("function2 printing"); }
void __wrap_print1 () { print2(); }
$ gcc main.c print.c && ./a.out
function1 printing
$ gcc -Wl,-wrap,print1 main.c print.c && ./a.out 
function2 printing
```

You don't need to modify `print1()` at all, but you can define `print2()` in the same file as `print1()`, and the override does not take effect unless you recompile.

**Idea 3:** If `print1()` is in a shared library, you can use a different shared library that defines an alternate version of `print1()` to override the original definition. You can load this different shared library on demand with `LD_PRELOAD`.

```
gcc main.c -o print1_test -lprint1
gcc -fPIC -c newprint1.c
gcc -shared -o newprint1.so newprint1.o
LD_PRELOAD=./newprint1.so ./print1_test
```

For this solution, not only does `print1()` need to be in a different source file, but it needs to be compiled into and linked as a shared object. The new `print1()` override resides in a different source file and compiled into a different shared library. However, an override does not require a recompile.

Comment: Why would you redefine `printf` when you could do it more narrowly?

Comment: @sfstewman: I didn't know he could add code between the functions.

Comment: Thanks ,I just thinks something wrong.So can you tell me how to close it?

Comment: @LidongGuo: Just don't worry about it. You can just leave the question up as it is.

Comment: @jxh Sorry ,It is just a misunderstanding. With a little silly

Answer (score 2):

It's a hack, but the only portable (and really, reasonable) way to do this is to use the macro preprocessor.

After `print1` is defined, define `print2`:

```
void print2(void) { printf("function 2 is printing.\n"); }
```

Then, before `main`, use a `#define` to replace `print1` with `print2`:

```
#define print1 print2
```

Keep in mind that there are few legitimate uses for this in production code.  It's occasionally useful in debugging.  You'll also occasionally see it to redefine stdlib functions like `malloc`.  It's still a hack, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

For hiding a function in the sense of wrapping your own function around an existing function without replacing the orginal function's name please see my other answer on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17191529/694576