# How to view thread-events from a process in logs?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

Gdb shows thread events when threads are created and destroyed

For Example: A message like following is displayed when a thread is created.

```
 [New Thread 0x41e02940 (LWP 25582)]
```

Same way a message is displayed when thread is destroyed.

While not using gdb, Do we have a way to track thread events happening in a process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While not using gdb, Do we have a way to track thread events happening in a process?

GDB does *not* use any secret APIs, so you can write a (non-trivial) program to track thread creation and destruction events just like GDB does, using the same APIs.

But your question is likely: "is it possible to track/log thread creation and destruction events from within the process itself?".

You could interpose `pthread_create` and `pthread_exit` functions, and inject a "wrapper" function that will call the actual thread function the user provided. The wrapper function can print a message when it is called (new thread has just appeared), and after actual user-provided thread function returns (the thread is about to exit). Getting the details right is not entirely trivial, but is not terribly hard either. [This](http://www.itworld.com/UIR000929interposers) is a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, Looks like the sample on the link given is not uploaded http://www.itworld.com/downloads/UIR000929interposers1.txt properly. Do you have any other sample reference ?

Comment: @Tectrendz: On how to write a logging wrapper this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17191529/694576 just replace "system" with the name of the function you want to wrap.