# Prepend function call with some code using Macro in C

Tags: c, macros, wrapper

I have a call to a function foo(a,b,c) in a C file which I want to prepend with some code. Can I do this with macro? Basically, I want to do the following:
Replace

```
add(a,b,c)
```

by

```
foo()
add(a,b,c)
```

Is it possible to achieve this with macro?

Comment: Why not define `bar(a,b,c) {foo(); return add(a,b,c);}` instead of a macro ?

Comment: `#define x(a,b,c) do {foo(); add(a,b,c);} while(0)`

Comment: @tux3 Can't `return` from macro.

Comment: @user4419802 The question asks for a macro, but I'm wondering if defining a function wouldn't be a cleaner solution in this case. (My `bar` was pseudocode for a function if that wasn't clear)

Comment: @tux3 Sure it would, but I assume TS wants inline solution.

Comment: @user4419802 And I'm left wondering why. In the vast majority of cases, the decision of whether to inline should be left to the compiler. Unless there's a good reason, which I'm not seeing.

Comment: You can find an answer on how to wrap a function here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17191529/694576

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int add(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

void foo() {
    printf("Foo!\n");
}

int add2(int a, int b, int c) {
    foo();
    return add(a, b, c);
}

#define add(a, b, c) add2((a), (b), (c))

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", add(5, 3, 1));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As macros don't expand recursively, the following is possible:

```
#define add(a, b, c) ( foo() , add((a), (b), (c)) )
```

The `add` in the replacement refers to the function, not the macro. This approach, however, has a few pitfalls: Taking the address and using a function pointer will refer to the real function, not the macro, as would enclosing `add` in parentheses as in `(add)(a, b, c)`.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can define a macro

```
#define foo(a,b,c) {foo(); add(a,b,c);}
```

Comment: Your macro won't work if `add` returns something for instance.

Comment: I want a way to capture the function call(alongwith arguments and return parameters) in some sort of handle in macro.

Comment: Do I understand it well that you want to capture all invocations of all functions and prepend them with a call to `foo`?

Answer (score 0):

If C++ `inline` function is not an option then use comma operator:

```
#define bar(a, b, c) (foo(), add((a), (b), (c)))
```

Comment: @Maxime Wrong. 'Comma' returns the last part always.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. But you should probably add parenthesis to avoid some problems: `printf("%d", bar(a, b, c))` will print the value returned by `foo` and not `add`.

Comment: @Maxime Yes, that's better. Although it's not possible to prevent all side-effects anyway.